# How to go through while loop again?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Im making a simple question and answer app in python , in this specific example it displays a word in simple chinese and gives two answers to pick wrong or right , i'm struggling to present a new question without restarting my code. This my go at making an app that helps me learn chinese and I wanted to use minimum help , hence the weird code.

For example :
the question is what is 1+1 and the user answered two then I want to go thourgh the code again an present the next question.

the specific section im trying the run from inside a function, so when the user answers correctly or incorrectly by pressing the button in the function I want to go through the code again and present my next question

`

```
    # ans
    def button_1(event):
        if Ans_option1.text == ans_or_not["ans"]:
            print('correct')
            return 'correct'

            

        else:
            print("incorrect")

    def button_2 (event):
        if Ans_option2.text == ans_or_not["ans"]:
            print('correct')
            return 'correct'

        else:
            print("incorrect")
    Ans_option1 = gp.Button(app,return_1(), button_1)
    Ans_option2 = gp.Button(app,return_2(),button_2)

    app.add(Ans_option1,3,2, align = 'center')
    app.add(Ans_option2,3,4, align = 'center')
    app.run()
```

`

whole code

```
import gooeypie as gp 
import random

app = gp.GooeyPieApp ('hello')


app.set_size (1000,500)
i = 2
n =3
while True :
    # use dictionary instead of lists so we c an have an answer to the questions
    question_dict = {

            'xihuan' : 'like',
            'Wo': 'I',
            'Ni': 'you' 

        }
    # random picks a value from a list of values made here
    picker =  random.choice(list(question_dict.values()))
    # I remake the same list here again as the indexing stays the same then find the index for the random value
    ind = list(question_dict.values()).index(picker)

    # I make a list of the keys and they have mathing indexes to their values and we use the index number given to us previously to find the key
    final  = list(question_dict.keys())[ind]
    # print(final)
    test = 1
    def question ():
        

        question_dict.pop(final)
        print(question_dict)
        # return final
        
        return final
        

    ans_or_not = {

            # this works first before the item is popped so it can cause a they same two words to appear on the buttons
            # varialbe from inside the functions arent stected outside , making this whole dictionary meaningless
            'ans' : picker,
            'non' : random.choice(list(question_dict.values()))





        }
        

    print(ans_or_not["non"])
    print(ans_or_not["ans"])

    while ans_or_not["non"] == ans_or_not["ans"]:
        ans_or_not.pop('non')
        print(ans_or_not)
        ans_or_not['non'] = random.choice(list(question_dict.values()))
        

    print(ans_or_not["non"])
    print(ans_or_not["ans"])


    nums = random.randrange(1,3)
    print(nums)



    def return_1():


        # while anss == nons :
        #   anss = random.randrange(0,2)
        #   print(anss + ','+ nons)

        if nums == 1 :
            return ans_or_not["ans"]

        if nums == 2:
            return ans_or_not["non"]


    def return_2():


        # while anss == nons :
        #   anss = random.randrange(0,2)
        #   print(anss + ','+ nons)

        if nums == 1 :
            return ans_or_not["non"]

        elif nums == 2:
            return ans_or_not["ans"]







    # design and layout
    def menu_select (event):
        pass
        menu_path = ' > '.join(event.menu)
        status.text = menu_path


    app.add_menu_item('Menu 1', 'Item 1', menu_select)



    # grid setup
    app.set_grid(4,5)
        
    question_lbl = gp.Label(app,question())
    app.add(question_lbl,2,3, align = 'center')


    # ans
    def button_1(event):
        if Ans_option1.text == ans_or_not["ans"]:
            print('correct')
            return 'correct'

            

        else:
            print("incorrect")

    def button_2 (event):
        if Ans_option2.text == ans_or_not["ans"]:
            print('correct')
            return 'correct'

        else:
            print("incorrect")
    Ans_option1 = gp.Button(app,return_1(), button_1)
    Ans_option2 = gp.Button(app,return_2(),button_2)

    app.add(Ans_option1,3,2, align = 'center')
    app.add(Ans_option2,3,4, align = 'center')
    app.run()
```

## What i've tried

i've tried using the continue function

- ways to restart while loops

Comment: Probably `app.run()` runs the app infinitely. Running something infinitely in an infinite loop (while True) has the effect that the outer loop doesn't make progress any more.

Comment: Your whole program looks ... strange. To me it seems that you didn't understand *several* concepts of Python and object oriented programming. You'd better have someone who spends ~4 hours with you and cleans up the code, explaining everything during the cleanup process.

Comment: Any suggestions for concepts to focus on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You have the problem wrong.

This is going to sound really complicated, but stay with me. So what app.run() does is start the program, and it displays what you have already added to it. By putting app.run() in the while loop, despite calling it multiple times, will only call once. What you need to do is draw the label and buttons, run the app, then start the while loop. In fact, I wouldn't use a while loop here at all. Instead, I would have is so you have a dictionary for the right and wrong answers, then simply modify that and the button text when you get the answer correct. I don't really understand your code, but it would look something like:

```
#function for choosing answer
#function for checking button one
#function for checking button two
#draw button one and two and label
app.run()
```

Also, you would have it so that if you got the answer right, you would choose a new one.